# Flink database connection

Tags: mysql, connection-pooling, apache-flink

Flink database connection problem when I want to write or read some data with Flink `sinkFunction` to MySQL.The data size is small in every operation. But there may be many `sinkFuction` invoked at the same time. I want to know if there is a better way to solve this problem with low cost?

Answer (score 0):

So you could use `RichSinkFunction` and override methods `open` and `close` to create and destroy connections to MySQL. Or maybe using Table API with Table Sink is a better way (you can find more information here: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/table/sourceSinks.html#define-a-tablesink)